# Converting Perl regex to python regex

Tags: python, regex, perl

I have been asked to convert a perl script to python.

I have no knowledge of perl scripting.

The perl script contains these lines of code :

```
 1. if ($option =~ "Fed5") 
 2. if (($option =~ m/Fed5/i) && ($option =~ m/KD/i)) 
 3. if (($option =~ m/Fed5/i) && ($option !~ m/KD/i))
```

I understood that this is related to perl regex.

Please let me know how can I get a python equivalent of above statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. if ($option =~ "Fed5")
```

equivalent python code:

```
if re.search(r'Fed5', option):
```

Perl code:

```
2. if (($option =~ m/Fed5/i) && ($option =~ m/KD/i))
```

equivalent python code:

```
if re.search(r'(?i)Fed5', option) and re.search(r'(?i)KD', option):
```

Perl code:

```
if (($option =~ m/Fed5/i) && ($option !~ m/KD/i))
```

equivalent python code:

```
if re.search(r'(?i)(?!.*kd)Fed5', option):
```

I have shorten the third condition.

OR use a double if condition.

```
if re.search(r'(?i)Fed5', option):
    if not re.search(r'(?i)kd', option):
```

Answer (score 1):

The m in perl just means to match the regex between //
and the /i is a modifier that says to ignore case.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html

The =~ operator is a binding operator: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators

So:

- 1. Match the string Fed5
- 2. Match the string Fed5 ignoring case, and match the string KD also ignoring case.
- 3. Match the string Fed5 ignoring case, and not match KD also ignoring case.